# Hovering parent child dynamic allocation

Tags: javascript

I am generating projects from CMS, and I am creating for each a container with an image and a sliver with a text box.. The image will represent the project image and textbox will represent the title.. A cover element is used to put over both the image and the sliver, so you have a clean hover experience.

I would like to have a hover method for each of them that addresses the underlying image and sliver. I prefer to use velocity if possible, although I think - since it is only opacity change and scale, I could also switch to full CSS.

Main question here is, how can I access the image and sliver elements, lying in the same container_project element. This when the cover element is being hovered?

Is there a way I can go to the parent element and then go back to the associated child with certain class/ id and then perform an action on that child?

--- in the code snippet you see an action performed on the cover element itself, I would like to perform an action on the underlying elements in the same container ---

```js
// create main flexbox 
    var flexbox_projects = document.createElement("div");
    flexbox_projects.className = "flex-container";
    flexbox_projects.id = "flexbox_projects";
    document.getElementById("body").appendChild(flexbox_projects);
  
  
    for (i=0; i<7; i++){
  
      // flexbox container
      var container_project = document.createElement("div");
      container_project.className = "container_project";
      container_project.id = "cont_project";
      document.getElementById("flexbox_projects").appendChild(container_project);
  
      // container for image and sliver 
      var container_elements = document.createElement("div");
      container_elements.className = "container_elements";
      container_project.appendChild(container_elements);
  
      // project image
      var image_project = document.createElement("img");
      image_project.className = "main_picture";
      image_project.src = "https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/core-image-filters@2x.jpg";
      image_project.id = "main_pic";
      container_elements.appendChild(image_project);
  
      // sliver project 
      var sliver_project = document.createElement("div");
      sliver_project.className = "sliver_project";
      sliver_project.id = "sliver";
      container_elements.appendChild(sliver_project);
  
      // title project 
      var title_project = document.createElement("p");
      title_project.className = "title_project";
      sliver_project.appendChild(title_project);
      title_project.innerHTML = "test";
  
      // cover project 
      var cover_project = document.createElement("div");
      cover_project.className = "cover_project";
      cover_project.id = "cover";
      container_elements.appendChild(cover_project);
  
      // add hover methods to project 
      cover_project.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverProject);
      cover_project.addEventListener("mouseout", dehoverProject);
      
      }
      
      
      
      
      function hoverProject(e) {

  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "orange";

  // // shader disappears 
  // $("#main_pic").velocity({scale: "1.02"}, {easing: "ease-in", delay : 0, duration : 150});  
  // $("#sliver").velocity({opacity: "0"}, {easing: "ease-in", delay : 0, duration : 150});   

}

// on leaving the project 
function dehoverProject(e){

  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";  

  // // shader reappears 
  // $("#main_pic").velocity({scale: "1"}, {easing: "ease-in", delay : 0, duration : 150}); 
  // $("#sliver").velocity({opacity: "1"}, {easing: "ease-in", delay : 100, duration : 250});    

}
```

```css
// PROJECT STYLING 
.container_project{
    width: 30vw;
    height: 17vw;
}

.container_elements{
    position: absolute;
    width: 23vw;
    height: 13vw;
    z-index: 2;
}

.main_picture{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 0.25%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sliver_project{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 5;    
    text-align: center;  
    border: solid white 1px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.title_project{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: fatfrank, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;  
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.cover_project{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.flex-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 5%;
    height: 17vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    z-index: 5;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
    <body id="body">
    
        </body>
```

Comment: container_project.id = "cont_project"; An id has to be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some changes in your snippet to achieve what you wanted with vanilla javascript.

```js
// create main flexbox 
    var flexbox_projects = document.createElement("div");
    flexbox_projects.className = "flex-container";
    flexbox_projects.id = "flexbox_projects";
    document.getElementById("body").appendChild(flexbox_projects);
  
  
    for (i=0; i<7; i++){
  
      // flexbox container
      var container_project = document.createElement("div");
      container_project.className = "container_project";
      container_project.id = "cont_project";
      document.getElementById("flexbox_projects").appendChild(container_project);
  
      // container for image and sliver 
      var container_elements = document.createElement("div");
      container_elements.className = "container_elements";
      container_project.appendChild(container_elements);
  
      // project image
      var image_project = document.createElement("img");
      image_project.className = "main_picture";
      image_project.src = "https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/core-image-filters@2x.jpg";
      image_project.id = "main_pic";
      container_elements.appendChild(image_project);
  
      // sliver project 
      var sliver_project = document.createElement("div");
      sliver_project.className = "sliver_project";
      sliver_project.id = "sliver";
      container_elements.appendChild(sliver_project);
  
      // title project 
      var title_project = document.createElement("p");
      title_project.className = "title_project";
      sliver_project.appendChild(title_project);
      title_project.innerHTML = "test";
  
      // cover project 
      var cover_project = document.createElement("div");
      cover_project.className = "cover_project";
      cover_project.id = "cover";
      container_elements.appendChild(cover_project);
  
      // add hover methods to project 
      cover_project.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverProject);
      cover_project.addEventListener("mouseout", dehoverProject);
      
      }
      
      
      
      
      function hoverProject(e) { 
e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.main_picture').style.border = "1px solid orange";
e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.sliver_project').style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}

// on leaving the project 
function dehoverProject(e){
  e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.main_picture').style.border = "none";
e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.sliver_project').style.backgroundColor = "black";   

}
```

```css
// PROJECT STYLING 
.container_project{
    width: 30vw;
    height: 17vw;
}

.container_elements{
    position: absolute;
    width: 23vw;
    height: 13vw;
    z-index: 2;
}

.main_picture{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 0.25%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sliver_project{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 5;    
    text-align: center;  
    border: solid white 1px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.title_project{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: fatfrank, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;  
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.cover_project{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.flex-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 5%;
    height: 17vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    z-index: 5;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
    
        </body>
```

Comment: Thanks Prawin! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution through going to the parentnode of the element, so the container. From there, I looked for the element with a specific class name connected to the same container.

With this element, I called the velocity call to create the desired motion. 
Something else I needed to take into account was the dynamic naming of the elements.. 
So id = "sliver_project + i" going through the row..

Snippet cannot be run due to the velocity calls not being recognised as such.. But this way you get an idea of how I solved it..

```js
// INTERACTIONS WITH PROJECT 
// on hovering the project 
function hoverProject(e) {

  // get the id from the parentnode 
  var parentnode = document.getElementById(e.target.parentNode.id);

  // get the child elements from the parentnode 
  var image_change = parentnode.querySelector(".main_picture").id;
  var sliver_change = parentnode.querySelector(".sliver_project").id; 

  console.log(e.target.parentNode);

  // shader disappears 
  $("#" + image_change).velocity({scale: "1.02"}, {easing: "ease-in", delay : 0, duration : 150});  
  $("#" + sliver_change).velocity({opacity: "0"}, {easing: "ease-in", delay : 0, duration : 150});   

}

// on leaving the project 
function dehoverProject(e){

  // get the parentnode through id from the parentnode
  var parentnode = document.getElementById(e.target.parentNode.id);

  // with id from the parentnode, go look for child elements 
  var image_change = parentnode.querySelector(".main_picture").id;
  var sliver_change = parentnode.querySelector(".sliver_project").id; 

  // shader reappears 
  $("#" + image_change).velocity({scale: "1"}, {easing: "ease-in", delay : 0, duration : 150}); 
  $("#" + sliver_change).velocity({opacity: "1"}, {easing: "ease-in", delay : 100, duration : 250});    

}



// create main flexbox 
  var flexbox_projects = document.createElement("div");
  flexbox_projects.className = "flex-container";
  flexbox_projects.id = "flexbox_projects";
  document.getElementById("body").appendChild(flexbox_projects);


  for (i=0; i<7; i++){

    // flexbox container
    var container_project = document.createElement("div");
    container_project.className = "container_project";
    container_project.id = "cont_project";
    document.getElementById("flexbox_projects").appendChild(container_project);

    // container for image and sliver 
    var container_elements = document.createElement("div");
    container_elements.className = "container_elements";
    container_elements.id = "cont_element" + i;
    container_project.appendChild(container_elements);

    // project image
    var image_project = document.createElement("img");
    image_project.className = "main_picture";
    image_project.id = "main_pic" + i;
    container_elements.appendChild(image_project);

    // sliver project 
    var sliver_project = document.createElement("div");
    sliver_project.className = "sliver_project";
    sliver_project.id = "sliver"+ i ;
    container_elements.appendChild(sliver_project);

    // title project 
    var title_project = document.createElement("p");
    title_project.className = "title_project";
    sliver_project.appendChild(title_project);
    title_project.innerHTML = "test";

    // cover project 
    var cover_project = document.createElement("div");
    cover_project.className = "cover_project";
    cover_project.id = "cover";
    container_elements.appendChild(cover_project);

    // add hover methods to project 
    cover_project.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverProject);
    cover_project.addEventListener("mouseout", dehoverProject);

    // have all projects appear with stagger 
    $(".container_elements").velocity({opacity: "1"}, { stagger: 10, duration: 100 });

    // populate from CMS 
    title_project.innerHTML = portfolioProject.projectTitel;
    image_project.src = portfolioProject.overzichtsfotoProject[0].url;

    }
```

```css
// PROJECT STYLING 
.container_project{
    width: 30vw;
    height: 17vw;
}

.container_elements{
    position: absolute;
    width: 23vw;
    height: 13vw;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
}

.main_picture{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 0.25%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sliver_project{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 5;    
    text-align: center;  
    border: solid white 1px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.title_project{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: fatfrank, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;  
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.cover_project{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.flex-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 5%;
    height: 17vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    z-index: 5;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
    <body id="body">
    
    </body>
```